# Sequelize JS - Delete all the associations using user id

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

User has been associated with other tables as shown below

```
    models.user.hasOne(models.plan, {foreignKey: 'plan_id'});
    models.user.hasOne(models.api, { foreignKey: 'user_id'});
    models.user.hasOne(models.user_profile, { foreignKey: 'user_id'});
```

I have tried to delete all the data in the tables using

```
{onDelete: 'CASCADE'}
```

```
model.user.destroy({
 where: {
   id: 2 --> This 2 is user ID
 }
})
```

**But this is not working. The only record from the user table is deleted but not from other tables. How is it possible to delete the records using a single query?**